# c# - render list of checkboxes, always returned as checked

Tags: c#, checkbox

Dears,

Please could you help with below problem:

I want to render list of checkbox in my view.

```
                           @model IEnumerable<CFts.Models.CFModel>
                             ...
                            @foreach (var test in ViewBag.CF_list)
                            {

                                if (test.Text != "" && test.Text != " ")
                                {
                                     <div class="checkbox">
                                         <label><input value="@test.Value" id="CF_list_" name="CF_list_" @(test.Selected == true ? "checked" : "") type="checkbox"> @test.Text</label>
                                     </div>
                                 }
                            }
```

OK, checkbox on the page.

CF_list generated in controller (SelectListItem)

But problem that - if send this form, at least one of checkboxes all time marked as selected. For example: 1. I selected two chekckboxed, send form - everything is OK. 2. I remove all ticks and send form - one of the checkbox (last clicked) indicated as selected.

Why?

CF_List is SelectListItem

Another question:

Please could you help me to understand very simple thing

I have model with my class:

```
public class VendorAssistanceViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
public partial class CSModel : IEntity
{
    public CSModel()
    {

        VendorAssistances = new[]
        {
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "DJ/BAND" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Officiant" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Florist" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Photographer" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Videographer" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Transportation" },
        }.ToList();
    }


    public IList VendorAssistances { get; set; }
```

I have view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CSTS.Models.CSModel>

  ... some html code...
 and how here to show array of checkboxes from Model, using VendorAssistances ?
```

I know that this is very simple, I read a lot of docs, but still can not understand

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not set the checked attribute, let the value attribute determine whether it is checked or not.

Change

```
<label><input value="@test.Value" id="CF_list_" name="CF_list_" @(test.Selected == true ? "checked" : "") type="checkbox">@test.Text</label>
```

To

```
<label><input value="@test.Value" id="c_" name="CF_list_" type="checkbox">@test.Text</label>
```

UPDATE: Just to make this easier to understand..

Do not use a SelectListItem for CF_List, use this instead. SelectListItem is used for drop down lists.

```
public class CFListCheckbox
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; } // Add a property to know if the checkbox should be checked or not
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }  // Change as needed
}
```

In your GET action..

```
// Assign an ICollection<CFListCheckbox> to your ViewBag.CF_list 
ICollection<CFListCheckbox> cfListCB = cfCollection.Select(r => new CFListCheckbox()
{
    IsChecked = false,
    Text = r.SomeProp,
    Value = r.SomePropOrWhatever
}).ToList();
ViewBag.CF_list = cfListCB;
```

On your view, use the `Html.Checkbox` to create your checkboxes.

```
@foreach (var test in ViewBag.CF_list)
{    
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(test.Text))
    {
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.Checkbox("CF_list_", test.IsChecked, new { Value = test.Value }) @test.Text
            </label>
        </div>
    }
}
```

On your POST action, just set the `ViewBag.ViewBag.CF_list` in case your post fails and goes back to the view.

```
// Assign an ICollection<CFListCheckbox> to your ViewBag.CF_list 
ICollection<CFListCheckbox> cfListCB = cfCollection.Select(r => new CFListCheckbox()
{
    IsChecked = false,
    Text = r.SomeProp,
    Value = r.SomePropOrWhatever
}).ToList();

// Add logic to re-assign the IsChecked property for your ViewBag.CF_list
foreach(var entry in model.CF_list_)
{
    CFListCheckbox item = cfListCB.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Text == entry.SomeProp && r.Value == entry.SomePropOrWhatever);
    if(item != null)
    {
        item.IsChecked = true;
    }
}

ViewBag.CF_list = cfListCB;

return View(model);
```

Please note that the sample code is just to give you an idea on what you can do. It is not absolute. Optimize it as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But, if I remove @(test.Selected == true ? "checked" : "" how to show on the page  (after postback) that checkbox is checked?

Comment: If you are using asp.net MVC just return the posted model back to the view. `return View(model)`. But since you are using a viewbag, just set the `ViewBag.CF_list = model.CF_list_` or just like how you set it on your GET action.

Comment: Yes, it is returned in Selected attribute, but this attribute always true on last clicked checkbox

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I also ask you to help with new question? (started post already updated) ? Just for understanding, i Know that this is very simple )

Comment: @Fullbalanced please post a another question here in SO regarding your 2nd problem. We discourage multiple questions in a single post. Everyone will be glad to help you on your problems.

Comment: Thanks, I will create another post. Please could you explain cfCollection.Select - what does it mean ? What cfCollection ?

Comment: `cfCollection` is just a sample variable, It should be your source for populating the `ViewBag.CF_list`. In my sample, I assumed it to be a list or collection in which I utilized the `Select` method from linq to simplify the creation of the list for `CFListCheckbox `.